# Laplace transform of an multiplication of Dirac Delta function and a function

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

How to write general formula for finding Laplace transform of the following function $$L[u(t)\delta(x-a)]=?  $$

where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta$ is Dirac Delta function and $u(t)$ is unknown function.

**My answer:**

If I am not wrong, I found $$L[u(t)\delta(x-a)]=\int_a^\infty e^{-st}u(t)\,dt$$ and then , Can we simplify more?

Comment: Typo: $\delta(t-a)$? Use the definition of the Laplace transform and perform the integral using the $\delta$-function property. Note that you should get a different answer depending on if $a > 0$ or $a < 0$.

Comment: No. I wrote correctly. If I am not wrong, I found $L[u(t)\delta(x-a)]=\int_a^\infty e^{-st}u(t)\,dt$ and then?

Comment: Then this makes very little sense / or is trivial. If the Laplace transform is wrt $t$ then $\delta(x-a)$ would just factors out of the integral. Also if it's $\delta(t-a)$ then what you did is not how the delta-function works. Go back to the definition of it.